# Math Rule Sanity Check

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I was wondering if A. is as legal as B.

> ### A. $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2x)=0)$
>
> ### B.  $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2x))=\sin^{-1}(0)$

Currently I am high school, and usually if I take "short-cuts" in math then that is typically viewed as unethical.  I already have the solutions to the question already.  Is what I did in B. preferred over A., and why is it?

Comment: Usually, an equal sign cannot occur inside a function.

Comment: @SimpleArt Sorry I didn't find the right tag. I should find a better tag.

Comment: Those tags are probably more appropriate.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much unethical as sloppy and unclear. In **A**, the reader has to guess what you meant by the inverse sine of an equality unless you actually define it. It may be clear to you what you intended, but not necessarily to someone else.

If you do take the trouble to define it, then it's not really a shortcut anymore and would have been easier to do it properly in the first place.